# Adding two different values at once from one list using LINQ/Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

To clarify my title I'll give you an example of what I have and what I want to do ( actually I want to refactor some code).

So at first I add objects to a list:

`var Impedances = new List<Impedance>()`

with:

`Impedances.Add(new Impedance (R,X))` - R and X are double values.

Later on the codes loops through a big list of 'LinesOut' (searches for other possible Impedance objects) and then it does this calculation:

```
var sumRez = Impedances.Select(x => x.R).Sum();
var sumReak = Impedances.Select(y => y.X).Sum();
var result = (c * model.voltageUDN) / (Math.Sqrt(3) * GetModule(sumRez, sumReak));
```

The result is presented in View. 
The question is

**How can I change this code to have less declarations but do the call the Sum() for `sumRez` and `sumReak` in one line. Should I add more parameters to the Select() extension - if yes, how?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "less declarations" is a peculiar term, what are you really asking for here? Your code works fine as it is, why do you want to change it?

Comment: The reason for this is that I think that my code might be struggling in adding values  of Impedance() objects  since finding one takes time.

Comment: @Balttazarr "finding"? It's really unclear what are you asking, sounds like XY problem. Consider updating your post with realistic example and clear definition of the issue with the code. The way it is now the code is fine - all `Aggregate` / `GroupBy` constant tricks are simply less efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `.Aggregate` (which is used to take a sequence of values and reduce it down to a single value):

```
var sums = Impedances.Aggregate((i0, i1) => new Impedance() { R = i0.R + i1.R, X = i0.X + i1.X });
var result = (c * model.voltageUDN) / (Math.Sqrt(3) * GetModule(sums.R, sums.X));
```

How you create a new `Impedance` instance might be different, but that's basically the way it works.

Comment: Could you explain why Aggregate? It works fine anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following extension

```
public static class ImpedanceExtensions
{
    public static Impedance SumImpedance(this IEnumerable<Impedance> collection)
    {
        var totalImpedance = new Impedance();

        foreach (Impedance impedance in collection)
        {
            totalImpedance.X += impedance.X;
            totalImpedance.R += impedance.R;
        }

        return totalImpedance;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var sumImpedance = Impedances.SumImpedance();
var result = (c * model.voltageUDN) / (Math.Sqrt(3) * GetModule(sumImpedance.R, sumImpedance.X));
```

Comment: I know this works but still you add all of the `impedance.R` to one variable and the same with `impedance.X`.  What I want to have because I'm curious if there a possiblity to have the adding in some LINQ code or extension method form. For example(the syntax is wrong I know): Impedances.Select((x,y)=>(x.R).Sum() , (y.X).Sum())